# How to use tensorboard within a docker container across a ssh tunnel?

Tags: docker, ssh, tensorboard

I'm running a deep learning network on a remote GPU cluster and I'd like to use tensorboard to visualize my training and performance. The problem is I'm really confused on how to expose the port tensorboard uses to my local computer. Due to security and account permission reasons, I have to connect to this server through another server. I also have the complication of training my network within a docker container. I'm not super familiar with advanced ssh stuff or just networking stuff in general so I'm wondering how to accomplish this.

Here's a roadmap of how I connect:

local computer -> intermediate network -> GPU cluster -> docker container

I normally connect to the GPU cluster using

`ssh -X -J 2fly@intermediate.server 2try@XX.XXX.XX.XXX`.

My docker command looks like

`NV_GPU=all nvidia-docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm -p 5001:6006 -v path/to/data:/UserData/data -v path/to/code:/UserData/code -v path/to/logs:/UserData/logs -it container_name`

I've tried adding the -L option to my ssh command but I get an error saying

```
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed
```

EDIT:
Here's the output of `ssh -f -v -N -J 2fly@intermediate.server 2try@XX.XXX.XX.XXX –L 5001:XX.XXX.XX.XXX:5001` (with identifying info removed)

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 13: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l 2fly -v -W '[%h]:%p' intermediate.server
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l 2fly -v -W '[XX.XXX.XX.XXX]:22' intermediate.server
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 16000
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 13: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug1: Connecting to intermediate.server [address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to intermediate.server:22 as '2fly'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:key
debug1: Host 'intermediate.server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to intermediate.server ([address]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd XX.XXX.XX.XXX:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to XX.XXX.XX.XXX:22 as '2try'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:key
debug1: Host 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to XX.XXX.XX.XXX (via proxy).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5001 forwarded to remote address XX.XXX.XX.XXX:5001
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5001.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5001.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Comment: ssh -f -v -N -J 2fly@intermediate.server 2try@XX.XXX.XX.XXX –L 5001:XX.XXX.XX.XXX:5001 (can you post your try with the -L option?)

Comment: ssh -X -J -L 127.0.0.1:5001:0.0.0.0:5001 2fly@intermediate.server 2try@XX.XXX.XX.XXX.

Comment: Try this: ssh into your target host. like you use to, from there, open an ssh session back to your jump host with -R remotePort:localhost:LocalPort (ssh –R 5001:localhost:5001 2fly@intermediate.server) after this run: ssh -f -v -N –L 5001:localhost:5001 2fly@intermediate.server after this you should be able to access the targetPort on your local machine

Comment: I get a warning saying "remote port forwarding failed for listen port 5001" when I run that -R command. Running the command after it just causes it to hang on connecting to the intermediate server until it times out.

Comment: Maybe it is already taken? check with netstat -tulpn